# big-picture vs soft-question

Tags: discussion, tags

What's the intended difference between these two tags ? My question is motivated by the comments on [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/658/how-are-side-effects-handled-in-semantics). I tried trolling MO to discern the difference, and have failed so far. And no, "you know it when you see it" is not an acceptable answer :)

Comment: I think the question you linked to is both soft and big-picture.

Answer (score 8):

How about this:

[soft](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soft): "having a bland or mellow rather than a sharp or acid taste"

[big-picture](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/big+picture): "the entire perspective on a situation or issue —used with the"

A soft-question is subjective and argumentative without a precise answer and can be a question **about** theoretical computer science rather than being a question in it.

Examples: 
How would you teach X to undergrads? 
Why computer scientists do X when Y happens? 
Is theoretical computer science part of pure math? 
How long will it take to settle P vs NP in your opinion?

A big-picture question is higher-level question, and although it can be subjective and argumentative it does not need to be, and is a question **in** theoretical computer science.

Examples: 
What is the main idea behind Razborov-Rudich natural proofs? 
What are the obstacles to prove a super-polynomial lower-bound for SAT? 
Where did the idea of Domain theory came from? 
 What are the main objects and constructions used in crypto? 
Is there a program to settle Unique Games Conjecture? 
Is polynomial time Turing computable the right definition for feasible computation? 
What evidence do we have for Church-Turing thesis?

(sorry for the bias in my examples.)

Comment: This is a great answer.  We could put this in the FAQ with little editing.

Comment: Thank you. It is now CW, feel free to edit.